# Struts2 - How can i put a link/button in a label/span by using Struts2 tags?

Tags: tags, struts2

I think the title explain my quesion. I need to add a link (or a button) in a label/span (never understand the real difference) by using Struts2 tags.

```
<s:label cssClass="menu_span">
    <s:submit value="Login" />
</s:label>
```

This doesnt work. Also, i didnt see the `s:span` (like `s:html`, `s:body`, `s:head`, `s:title`, `s:img`, and so on...)

I tried to watch the tag references, but seems that isnt possible do it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to use Struts2 tags where standard HTML tags work fine (which is why there isn't an `s:html` tag, etc.) Tag libraries in JSP are there to simplify and standardize your HTML output to make it easier on you. When the tag syntax is practically the same as the output generated, they cease to be useful.

Second, what are you trying to achieve by wrapping a submit button in a label? Labels are used to associate text with a form element such as a radio button, checkbox, text field, etc. Buttons are already clickable, so I don't follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: First : ok, i thought it got every kind of tags, like happens for jsf. Secondo : i need a label/span to put a botton and set it in a custom space. Like put the botton in a 200px width (span) space. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to place the button in a span then (not a label). You can probably just apply CSS directly to the button to format it how you want, though.